# javascript array of object & function -- not working with

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This function call works if i sends parameters directly, function `is working as per expectation` :---

```
var VSCP_WEBSOCKET_URL="ws://192.168.1.20:7681";

vscpws_stateButton( VSCP_WEBSOCKET_URL,  // url
                    "Bedroom_Bedroom_Light",    // canvas for button
                     false,            // No local state change
                     94, 
                     true);   


vscpws_stateButton( VSCP_WEBSOCKET_URL,  // url
                    "Bedroom_Bedroom_Light",    // canvas for button
                     false,            // No local state change
                     94, 
                     true);
```

Now i want to call these functions & passing parameters stored in array.
And now i want to send parmeters to function by storing them in an array.
calling functions with parameters stored in an array `does not works` :---

```
var Device_Array= [
  { url: 'ws://192.168.1.20:7681', canvasName: 'Bedroom_Bedroom_Light', bLocal: 'false' , btnType: 94 , bNoState: 'true'
  }, 

  { url: 'ws://192.168.1.20:7681', canvasName: 'Bedroom_Bedroom_Light', bLocal: 'false' , btnType: 94 , bNoState: 'true'
  }
];


vscpws_stateButton( Device_Array[0].url,  // url
                    Device_Array[0].canvasName,    // canvas for button
                    Device_Array[0].bLocal,            // No local state change
                    Device_Array[0].btnType,            // Button type
                    Device_Array[0].bNoState);


vscpws_stateButton( Device_Array[1].url,  // url
                    Device_Array[1].canvasName,    // canvas for button
                    Device_Array[1].bLocal,            // No local state change
                    Device_Array[1].btnType,            // Button type
                    Device_Array[1].bNoState);
```

If i declare `btnType: '94'` in array then also logic does not work.

Please suggest is my syntax is correct for properties of objects stored in an array ?

Comment: Your array seems to be called `array` not `Device_Array`.

Comment: Your syntax looks correct and I don't see a reason your code wouldn't work (if your first snippet works)

Comment: i have corrected my code .. it was printing mistake while i was pasting the code..

Comment: yes working i put the wrong url ...